# Sending data as double float over UDP C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, udp, ip, port

**Hi everybody,**

**Brief of post:** I need help converting the script below to send data over UDP as a double float rather than in UTF8, with the data being sent acquired through the command 'transform.position.x' in Unity 3D     :) If you would like to know more please read on.

My university Masters project has been to develop a racing simulator, I've had the basics all working by sending vehicle position and rotation data from the simulation software to the visuals over UDP, and then in the visuals assigning the incoming data streams to each position or rotation vector for a 3D vehicle model. And now, as part of some system analysis I'm trying to measure any lag or latency caused by the communication or by the visual package running at a much lower frequency to the simulation software.

To measure this I want to control an object within the visual environment like normal but then have another separate script getting the coordinates of the object and sending them straight back to the simulation software on another port and that's the script I'm having trouble with as the data needs to be sent back as a double float.

Both the send and receive UDP scripts were originally sourced from a forum:
https://community.unity.com/t5/Multiplayer-Networking/simple-udp-implementation-send-read-via-mono-c/td-p/154952
The UDP Send script I am trying to modify is also shown below

At the moment, out of these two, only the receive script is being used and when I came across it it had already been modified to receive a double float and what I'm trying to do is modify the send script to send a double float as well, they were both originally written to send and receive UTF8 encoded text.

Also, the visual package is Unity 3D and the command 'transform.position.x' is one which gets the coordinate of an object and so this will be what is being sent, and then I will add the other position and rotation vectors once I understand the method.

Also, I should probably mention I have very little experience with coding as this isn't the main part of my project but would really appreciate some help as I'm getting no where with this tiny bit and am now running out of time.

Many thanks in advance!!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

public class UDPSend : MonoBehaviour {

private static int localPort;

// prefs
private string IP;  // define in init
public int port;  // define in init

// "connection" things
IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint;
UdpClient client;

// gui
string strMessage="";


// call it from shell (as program)
private static void Main()
{
    UDPSend sendObj=new UDPSend();
    sendObj.init();

    // testing via console
    // sendObj.inputFromConsole();

    // as server sending endless
    sendObj.sendEndless(" endless infos \n");

}
// start from unity3d
public void Start()
{
    init();
}

// OnGUI
void OnGUI()
{
    Rect rectObj=new Rect(40,380,200,400);
    GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
    style.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperLeft;
    GUI.Box(rectObj,"# UDPSend-Data\n127.0.0.1 "+port+" #\n"
            + "shell> nc -lu 127.0.0.1  "+port+" \n"
            ,style);

    // ------------------------
    // send it
    // ------------------------
    strMessage=GUI.TextField(new Rect(40,420,140,20),strMessage);
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(190,420,40,20),"send"))
    {
        sendString(strMessage+"\n");
    }      
}

// init
public void init()
{
    // Define end point , from which the messages are sent.
    print("UDPSend.init()");

    // define
    IP="127.0.0.1";
    port=16;

    // ----------------------------
    // Send
    // ----------------------------
    remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);
    client = new UdpClient();

    // status
    print("Sending to "+IP+" : "+port);
    print("Testing: nc -lu "+IP+" : "+port);

}

// inputFromConsole
private void inputFromConsole()
{
    try
    {
        string text;
        do
        {
            text = Console.ReadLine();

            // Send the text to the remote client .
            if (text != "")
            {

                // encode data with the UTF8 encoding to binary .
                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

                // Send the text to the remote client .
                client.Send(data, data.Length, remoteEndPoint);
            }
        } while (text != "");
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        print(err.ToString());
    }

}

// sendData
private void sendString(string message)
{
    try
    {
        //if (message != "")
        //{

        // encode data with the UTF8 encoding to binary .
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

        // Send the message to the remote client .
        client.Send(data, data.Length, remoteEndPoint);
        //}
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        print(err.ToString());
    }
}


// endless test
private void sendEndless(string testStr)
{
    do
    {
        sendString(testStr);


    }
    while(true);

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for giving an answer so quickly, however I don't think that would be applicable in my situation as the simulation software is Modelica based and, as far as I know, doesn't work with UTF8 encoding which is why I was looking to change it.

However, after posting this I had an idea and using Youtube and other forums I was able to write a script that converted the double floats into integer values and multiplied them by 1e6 and then sent and received them as an integer and just divided them in the simulation software again to get them back as a decimal.

...And then found out I can just use that method to send it straight as a double.

I'll post the script here in case it's useful for anyone:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

public class LatencyTest : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
public void Update () {

    // Get coordinates
    double x = transform.position.x;

    // Create byte array for sending
    byte[] coordinates = BitConverter.GetBytes(x);

    // Define IP Address and Port
    string IP = "127.0.0.1";
    int port= 16;
    Socket client;
    IPEndPoint Dymola;

    //Send to IP Address on the port specified above
    Dymola = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse (IP), port);
    client = new Socket (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    client.SendTo (coordinates, Dymola);
    //print (coordinates);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the existing sendString(string message) function you can do this...

```
sendString(transform.position.x.ToString());
```

This will send the x position as a UTF8 string, you can parse the UTF8 string into a double after receiving the udp message using...

```
Double.Parse(string udpMessage);
```

For more reference on Double.Parse see...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt(v=vs.110).aspx

This is probably not the most efficient way but should work fine with the existing code.

EDIT: To follow up with how you'd do this to get the entire position and rotation in one udp message you could do something like this...

```
string message = transform.position.x + "," 
               + transform.position.y + "," 
               + transform.position.z + ","
               + transform.rotation.x + ","
               + transform.rotation.y + ","
               + transform.rotation.z;
sendString(message);
```

then on the receiving side you would do this...

```
string[] messageParts = udpMessage.Split(',');
Vector3 position = new Vector3(
                       Double.Parse(messageParts[0]), 
                       Double.Parse(messageParts[1]),
                       Double.Parse(messageParts[2])
                       );
Vector3 rotation = new Vector3(
                       Double.Parse(messageParts[3]), 
                       Double.Parse(messageParts[4]),
                       Double.Parse(messageParts[5])
                       );
```

And so on.... Good luck.